# Zoom event like Google news

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, layout

I have to make something like zooming behavior of [Google News](https://news.google.co.in/?ar=1339141747). When we zoom in two three times he left sidebar hides out. How we can do that? What I know is first we have to detect zoom event. As I searched SO and also did some googling, I came to know that there is no direct zoom event present in HTML-DOM. There are some ways to do so like
:

1. Using `onresize` event which will fire two times when we zoom in or out. But now how can we detect it is zoom in or out. One way is compare dimension of any element before and after the `onresize` event. But is there anything else to that.

I tried to find the how google news implements it but not much win. Pls help me out

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@media` queries in your CSS. For eg., if your browser `width` is `1024`, you show one content, but if it is less, you don't. A code for this would be:

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .left-sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
    .left-sidebar {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

It is not supported yet in IE 7 and IE 8! You need to use JavaScript or jQuery to trigger in that case. Try it out. :) Hope it helps! :)

Check out a basic example here [Media Query Demo](http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/221_responsive_widget/Media-Query-Files-DEMO/index.html). Resize your browser width and check out the bottom part.

The CSS of that is:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    body:after {
        content: "320 to 480px";
        background-color: hsla(90,60%,40%,0.7);
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body:after {
        content: "480 to 768px";
        background-color: hsla(180,60%,40%,0.7);
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    body:after {
        content: "768 to 1024px";
        background-color: hsla(270,60%,40%,0.7);
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    body:after {
        content: "1024 and up";
        background-color: hsla(360,60%,40%,0.7);
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to zoom in and out of the document. The min-width and max-width don't change with zooming as everything is liquid. As you see in google news (if you tried to zoom in). Media queries are useful if screen size is changing but not if we zoom in.

Comment: Okay, then will use the jQuery function `$(window).resize()` and add the necessary classes to hide the elements. :)